# CiviEvent Widget: Link to register is broken

Tags: civievent

CiviEvent Widget shortcode will list event like this:
[image]

However the "Register Now" link for the event is not correct. The url the widget provides is: mysite.com/&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=6

The correct url should be: mysite.com/?page_id=5&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=6

Any suggestions on why this is happening?
Running: WP 5.9.1, CiviCRM 5.42.1

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?
In outbound emailing, I found a workaround : I insert manually the missing "?page_id=5" in the URL, in civimail.
But once a user register to an event online, or fill a profile form, the URL after completion is wrong and leads to HTTP 404 error because of the missing "?page_id=5":

https://www.mydomain.org/&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Finfo&reset=1&id=1